# modal box opens wrong one if pressed before page loads fully

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I have two different modal boxes on my site. And if I press the button which loads them before the page is fully loaded, it loads the wrong modal box (always the first one).

How can I fix this issue? Would it be plausible to disable buttons until page is fully loaded? Or is there another method that would be more UI friendly?

Comment: I'd suggest you post the jQuery script you're using, and, perhaps, a link to the relevant modal plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always put the calls to the modal plugin into a `$(window).load(function(){ /* ... */ })` event-handler, rather than `$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ });`, which would prevent the modal dialogs being attached *until* the window has finished loading:

```
$(window).load(
    function(){
        $('#modalTriggerElementOne').modalPlugin();
        $('#modalTriggerElementTwo').otherModalPlugin();
    });
```

Failing that, you could simply disable the buttons in the `$(document).ready()` and then, on `$(window).load()` re-enable them:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:button').attr('disabled',true);
        /* ...other stuff... */
    });

$(window).load(
    function(){
        $('input:button').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

But that seems unnecessarily clunky.

Obviously, if you can provide details of your code/script we might be able to provide better answers to your question.